# How to skip OR if AND statement row count is not 0

Tags: mysql

Heey Guys,

I have a question and i can't find the solution.
So this is my QUERY

```
SELECT * 
FROM `hwr_story` 
WHERE question_count = '8' 
AND (lower(subcategory) = lower('True') OR subcategory IS NULL)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Result:
http://cl.ly/image/1r0c2P0m3K07

So what i want, is if this return a row, i don't want the or statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `hwr_story` 
WHERE question_count = '8' AND lower(subcategory) = lower('True') 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

But if the row count is 0 then i want it to get

```
SELECT * 
FROM `hwr_story` 
WHERE question_count = '8' AND subcategory IS NULL 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Is there anyway to do this in one Query?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you should always group your `AND`s and `OR`s in your `WHERE` clause with parenthesis. Is your current `WHERE` clause supposed to be `(question_count = '8' AND lower(subcategory) = lower('True')) OR subcategory IS NULL`  or `question_count = '8' 
AND (lower(subcategory) = lower('True') OR subcategory IS NULL)`?

Comment: Yeah it's this one
WHERE question_count = '8'  AND (lower(subcategory) = lower('True') OR subcategory IS NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to limit your result to one row anyway, so just write your `order by` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hwr_story
WHERE question_count = '8' 
AND (lower(subcategory) = lower('True') OR subcategory IS NULL)
ORDER BY subcategory IS NULL, RAND() LIMIT 1
```

`subcategory IS NULL` returns 1 or 0, true or false. Then just sort ascending and you got it :)